# ImportError: cannot import name '_c_internal_utils' from partially initialized module 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib, conda, pypy

Today I created a [new Conda env based on `PyPy`](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/install.html#using-a-packaged-pypy) using this command:

```
conda create -pypy1 pypy
```

Then after activation, I started to install packages using the conda-forge channel. For example, I installed matplotlib using the conda-forge channel, and when I enter `conda list matplotlib` in the activated Conda env, I get this:

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Shayan\ypy1:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
matplotlib-base           3.5.1            py38hd77b12b_1
matplotlib-inline         0.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
```

But when I try to import matplotlib, I get this error:

```
>>> import matplotlib
----> 1 import matplotlib

File c:\Users\Shayan\ypy1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:109, in <module>
    105 from packaging.version import parse as parse_version
    107 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    108 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 109 from . import _api, _version, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
    110 from matplotlib.cbook import MatplotlibDeprecationWarning, sanitize_sequence
    111 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation  # deprecated

File c:\Users\Shayan\ypy1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py:31, in <module>
     28 import numpy as np
     30 import matplotlib
---> 31 from matplotlib import _api, _c_internal_utils
     32 from matplotlib._api.deprecation import (
     33     MatplotlibDeprecationWarning, mplDeprecation)
     36 @_api.deprecated("3.4")
     37 def deprecated(*args, **kwargs):

ImportError: cannot import name '_c_internal_utils' from partially initialized module 'matplotlib' (most likely due to a circular import) (c:\Users\Shayan\ypy1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py)
```

How can I fix this, and what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The command `conda create -n pypy1 pypy` will use the default python version 3.8. The migration on conda-forge for pypy3.8/3.9 packages started a few months ago but matplotlib has not yet been migrated. I am not sure what package you got, but it is not one that can work with pypy3.8.

You can tell conda "please use pypy3.7" via `conda create -pypy1 pypy python=3.7`

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for this great help! So, after that, I should install packages using `pypy -mpip install <NAME_Of_PACKAGE>` instead of `conda install ...`?